# Hide Modal in Twitter Bootstrap when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is a sample code from twitter bootstrap but . . .

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The scenario is this: I have a redirect page and I want to display the modal. Yes, of course I made it displayed but how do I close it? I tried different ways the click function but nothing happened.

Answer (score 5):

From bootstrap doc :

**Manually hides a modal.**

```
.modal('hide')

$('.modal').modal('hide')
```

So if you want to hide it on `click` you can bind this action to the `click` `event`

```
$('#yourid').on('click' , function() { 
  $('.modal').modal('hide')
});
```

if you want to hide it after some second that you loaded the document you can try with a `timeout`

```
$(function(){  //document ready
..
.. //your code
..

 setTimeout(function(){
       $('.modal').modal('hide')
 }, 2000);  //2000 = 2 second

..
})
```

**UPDATE 1**

To bind it on the close `button` give him a `class` or `id`

```
<a href="#" class="btn closebtn">Close</a>
```

now

```
$('.closebtn').on('click',function() {
   $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

If you want to bind only on that `close` `button` use an `id` instead of a `class`

Comment: It didn't worked for me. . 
Observe that <div class="modal"> no (hide and fade class)
after redirected it is not hidden..

Comment: can you explain it better ? Probably nobody really got you're issue.

Comment: Ok, ex. I'm at the home page and after submitting the form I will be redirected to another page and that page has already a modal displayed This code 
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3>Modal header</h3>
    </div>
<div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#" class="btn">Close</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
    </div>
</div>
The problem is how to close the modal?

Comment: dude the code I wrote must work , I use bootstrap too and it does. Are you having any console error?

Comment: when do you want to hide your modal ?

Comment: when I clicked close or the x button it should hide the modal

Answer (score 1):

Old post but this can now be done using HTML attributes.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If it's still needed you can try to put your 'click' event in another event 'shown.bs.dropdown' like so:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  $('#yourid').on('click' , function() { 
    $('#myDropdown').modal('hide');
  });
});
```

In my case the 'click' event wasn't binded when the modal was shown. So when I put it in 'show.bs.dropdown' event, everything went as I expected. 'click' was binded to modal as soon as modal was shown.