# Modal 'close' not working

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

I've taken a working script and adjusted it to allow for multiple independent modals and I am no longer able to close any of the modals. I receive the error:

> Cannot set property 'display' of undefined at HTMLSpanElement.span.onclick

Neither the window.onclick or document.onclick functions are working. [Here's the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/longdevity/8nyahu6z/6/)

```
<div class="contentSection">
    <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-one">Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-one" class="popupModal modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modalContent">
        <p>Here's some content!</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contentSection">
    <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-two">...Or Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-two" class="popupModal modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <div class="modalContent">
        <p>Here's some different content!</p>
    </div>
</div>


var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('popupModal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("popupBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
    var thisBtn = btn[i];
    thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }, false);
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide Modal in Twitter Bootstrap when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163476/hide-modal-in-twitter-bootstrap-when-clicked)

Comment: @C.Lightfoot that's Bootstrap modal, this is a custom one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`modal` is an `HTMLCollection` (array like object), as you have class `popupModal` for more than one element.
So you need to iterate through the array and set `display = none` for all.

Also, you have assigned `click` for the first `close` element only, so you need to iterate through the `span` elements and attach `click` for both span elements to close both modal windows.

Or, you can just iterate through the `modal` array and attach event listener to close the modal if `event.target` is  `span`.

```js
var modal = document.getElementsByClassName('popupModal');
var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("popupBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  var thisBtn = btn[i];
  thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }, false);
}


for (var i = 0; i < modal.length; i++) {
  modal[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if(e.target.className === 'close') {
      this.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.popupBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalContent {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 8px solid #81c8e8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #222;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.close {
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #2b3d52;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentSection">
  <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-one">Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-one" class="popupModal modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modalContent">
    <p>
      Here's some content!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contentSection">
  <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-two">...Or Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-two" class="popupModal modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modalContent">
    <p>
      Here's some different content!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't close the second modal

Comment: Iterate through the "close" button as well. Only your first close button is working  - see the `span` variable. Will give an upvote if you make that correction.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer, `span` refers to the first element only, therefore click for only first modal works.

Comment: Ok, but you might as well make the minor correction and not post broken code.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a couple of things that were not right in your code:

1) you were using twice `var modal`

2) you subscribe to `onclick` of only one `<span></span>`

3) `var model = document.getElementsByClassName('popupModal');` will actually return a **[HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)** and this code:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

will never work(*you need to think to refactor it*)

So you need to capture the `click` of both spans and it should work

```js
var modals = document.getElementsByClassName('popupModal');
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("popupBtn");
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  var thisBtn = btns[i];
  thisBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var m = document.getElementById(this.dataset.modal);
    m.style.display = "block";
  }, false);
}

for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  var thisSpan = spans[i];
  thisSpan.addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  }, false);
}
```

```css
.popupBtn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modalContent {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 15% auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 8px solid #81c8e8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px #222;
  cursor: default;
  font-size: .9em;
}

.close {
  color: #ccc;
  float: right;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: ease-in-out .5s;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background-color: #2b3d52;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentSection">
  <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-one">Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-one" class="popupModal modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modalContent">
    <p>
      Here's some content!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="contentSection">
  <a class="popupBtn" data-modal="modal-window-two">...Or Open Me!</a>
</div>

<div id="modal-window-two" class="popupModal modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modalContent">
    <p>
      Here's some different content!
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```